# Installing Spring XD on Ambari

Tags: spring, hadoop, bigdata, spring-xd, ambari

I installed the following software:

- CentOS 6.7
- Apache Ambari 2.1.2

I try to install Spring XD via Ambari, so I read the following tutorial:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-xd-ambari/blob/master/src/docs/asciidoc/InstallingXDwithAmbari.asciidoc

When I try to install Spring XD via Ambari I see the following error:

[image]

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in that document you link to, the latest version of Ambari we support is 2.0.1. They keep changing things in Ambari so older scripts won't necessarily work in later versions. We are planning on updating the Sprig XD install script so it works with more recent versions, but we don't have a date yet. We have an issue tracking this here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-xd-ambari/issues/5